# Playframework renderJSON() array

Tags: java, json, playframework

I'm using renderJSON() method to return an array of objects, with a custom JsonSerializer for the class of each element. The response has the following format:

```
[{"id":2,"name":"fred"},{...},...]
```

But I would like to add the name of the array at the begginning:

```
"arrayname":[{"id":2,"name":"fred"},{...},...]
```

How can I add the name of the object to a JSON response with renderJSON()? Should I use a template or can I do it with java code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"arrayname":[{"id":2,"name":"fred"},{...},...]
```

looks like invalid Json, but if you wrap the array in an object you could get:

```
{"arrayname":[{"id":2,"name":"fred"},{...},...]}
```

E.g. something like this:

```
public class MyArrayWrapper {
    public final User[] arrayname;
    public MyArrayWrapper(User[] arrayname) {
        this.arrayname = arrayname;
    }
}
```

Then you can call `renderJSON(new MyArrayWrapper(yourUserArray));` to get JSON like:

```
{"arrayname":[{"id":2,"name":"fred"},{...},...]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just return as a list Arrays.asList(arr);